# how to add dynamic properties to entities at run time

Tags: entity-framework, dynamic-linq

I'm using Dynamic Linq to select a few fields from a database query

Lets say I have following class

```
Class User
 Property LastName as string
 Property Email as string
End Class
```

But I want to call the query like this

```
dim q= MyContext.Set("User").Select("new (LastName, FirstName)")
```

I obviously get an error

> System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException: 'No property or field 'FirstName' exists in type 'User''

Even though I have the field in the database

So the question is: How can I tell `EF` at run time, that the User Class has a field FirstName. Even though it was not declared in code?

I looked at all the documentation about `OnModelCreating`, but can't seem a way to add a new property, only configure existing/known properties.

any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I got a freelancer to write me some code, but its not really working (he just took the money before i had time to test it)

this is what I added to my OnModelCreating

```
Dim asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType(FieldTypes))
            Dim asb = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(New AssemblyName(asm.FullName), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
            Dim modb = asb.DefineDynamicModule(t.Module.Name)
            Dim builder = modb.DefineType("Dynamic" & t.Name, TypeAttributes.Public Or TypeAttributes.Class, t)
            builder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public)
            Dim tbl = t.GetSchemaTable.Table
            Dim newcols = dbcols.Where(Function(x) x.ObjectName = tbl)
            For Each column In newcols
                If t.GetProperty(column.Name) Is Nothing Then
                    Dim dt As Type
                    Select Case column.TypeName
                        Case "int" : dt = GetType(Integer)
                        Case "nvarchar" : dt = GetType(String)
                        Case "datetime2" : dt = GetType(Date)
                        Case "bit" : dt = GetType(Boolean)
                    End Select
                    CreateAutoImplementedProperty(builder, column.Name, dt)
                End If
            Next                
mthd.MakeGenericMethod(builder.CreateType).InvokePlus(modelBuilder)
```

and here is the function used

```
Private Sub CreateAutoImplementedProperty(ByVal builder As TypeBuilder, ByVal propertyName As String, ByVal propertyType As Type)
        Dim fieldBuilder = builder.DefineField(String.Concat("m_", propertyName), propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private)
        Dim propertyBuilder = builder.DefineProperty(propertyName, System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, Nothing)
        Dim propertyMethodAttributes = MethodAttributes.Public Or MethodAttributes.SpecialName Or MethodAttributes.HideBySig
        Dim getterMethod = builder.DefineMethod(String.Concat("get_", propertyName), propertyMethodAttributes, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes)
        Dim getterILCode = getterMethod.GetILGenerator()
        getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
        getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder)
        getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
        Dim setterMethod = builder.DefineMethod(String.Concat("set_", propertyName), propertyMethodAttributes, Nothing, New Type() {propertyType})
        Dim setterILCode = setterMethod.GetILGenerator()
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1)
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder)
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getterMethod)
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setterMethod)
    End Sub
```

But if this code runs, then I lose my debugging in VS. Trying to get the value of variables in watch/immediate windows gives me the following error:

> error BC31091: Import of type 'FieldTypes' from assembly or module
> 'MyClass.dll' failed.

If I comment out this code. Everything is back to normal. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to construct a new type which has that property, you can use the `DynamicClassFactory` from [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core)

You can use this like:

```cs
var props = new DynamicProperty[]
{
  new DynamicProperty("FirstName", typeof(FirstName))
};

var type = DynamicClassFactory.CreateType(props);
var dynamicClass = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as DynamicClass
dynamicClass.SetDynamicProperty("Name", "Test");
```

See https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/src/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/DynamicClassFactory.cs#L172